# When importing a TIFF image into Google Earth Engine, I can't view it as it's completely black

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to import a TIFF (Landcover) file into my GEE working folder.
The image I get is completely black and without information about the floor coverings.

Answer (score 2):

this might be happening because of the way you are displaying your asset.

try providing a color palette in your visualization parameters.

for instance, let's say you have 3 clases of land cover (10,20,30)

```
var vispar = {min:10, max:30, palette:['FF9800','AB56BG','TT45GG']}

Map.addLayer( your_layer, vispar, 'yourlayer')
```

Adjust the number of colors to the number of your classes.

I hope this helps,

F.